# ERROR : could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

I'm using raspberry model 3B+ , I made a venv and then tried to install tensorflow but I get these 2 errors
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none)`

`ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow`

I managed to install other libraries but only tensorflow I wasn't able to install.

Comment: Are you sure you're using Python 3? Try upgrading pip first `pip3 install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: @LTJ I did and still didn't work out

Comment: What is the command you ran to try to install tensor flow?

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer since i was in the VE i used pip3 install tensorflow

Answer (score 10):

I just had this issue on the latest Macbook Pro (Apple M1 Pro Chip). The solution seems to be to `pip install tensorflow-macos`. This gave me an error `ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py` which I solved by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70587971/errorfailed-building-wheel-for-h5pyfailed-to-build-h5pyerrorcould-not-build-wh) post.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31699120)

Answer (score 1):

Could you please verify the below requirements:

1. Is your pc 64 bits, the python and os used should be 64 bits.
2. $ sudo pip3 install setuptools --upgrade
3. TensorFlow v2.4 is compatible with Python 3.6 - 3.8. For more information, please take a look at the [tested build configurations.](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu)

4. verify the below:
python --version, python -m pip --version and python -m pip install -vvv tensorflow [have latest version of all including tensorflow stable version 2.x]

Comment: thank you but it seems that raspberry latest versions (the full version) comes with a tenorflow installed in it because i didn't install it and yet i found out that i already have one